# Is it bad style to redundantly check a condition?

Tags: coding-style, clean-code

I often get to positions in my code where I find myself checking a specific condition over and over again.

I want to give you a small example: suppose there is a text file which contains lines starting with "a", lines starting with "b" and other lines and I actually only want to work with the first two sort of lines. My code would look something like this (using python, but read it as pseudocode):

```
# ...
clear_lines() # removes every other line than those starting with "a" or "b"
for line in lines:
    if (line.startsWith("a")):
        # do stuff
    elif (line.startsWith("b")):
        # magic
    else:
        # this else is redundant, I already made sure there is no else-case
        # by using clear_lines()
# ...
```

You can imagine I won't only check this condition here, but maybe also in other functions and so on.

Do you think of it as noise or does it add some value to my code?

Comment: It's basically about whether or not you are coding defensively. Do you see this code being edited a lot? Is it likely that this is going to be a part of a system which needs to be extremely reliable? I don't see much harm in shoving an ``assert()`` in there to help with testing, but beyond that is probably excessive. That said, it'll vary depending on the situation.

Comment: your 'else' case is essentially dead / unreachable code. Do check that there are no system wide requirements that prohibit this.

Comment: @NWS: are you saying that I should keep the else case? Sorry I don't understand you completely.

Comment: not especially related to the question - but I would make that 'assertion' into an invariant - which would require a new "Line" class (perhaps with derived classes for A & B), rather than treating the lines as strings and telling them what they represent from the outside. I'd be happy to elaborate on this over at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: did you mean `elif (line.startsWith("b"))`? by the way, you may safely remove those surrouding parenthesis on the conditions, they are not idiomatic in Python.

Comment: @tokland Yes I meant elif. I will edit my question. So omitting the parentheses is the pythonic way? ;)

Comment: @mcwise: yes, in Python they are not needed and add zero information (but note that they are ok in a multi-line condition).

Comment: @mcwise i am saying you should check your projects software requirements !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an excedingly common practice and the way of dealing with it is via higher-order [filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28higher-order_function%29).

Essentially, you pass a function to the filter method, along with the list/sequence that you want to filter against and the resulting list/sequence contains only those elements that you want.

I'm unfamiliar with python syntax (though, it does contain such a function as seen in the link above), but in c#/f# it looks like this:

c#:

```
var linesWithAB = lines.Where(l => l.StartsWith("a") || l.StartsWith("b"));
foreach (var line in linesWithAB)
{
    /* line is guaranteed to ONLY start with a or b */
}
```

f# (assumes ienumerable, otherwise List.filter would be used):

```
let linesWithAB = lines
    |> Seq.filter (fun l -> l.StartsWith("a") || l.StartsWith("b"))

for line in linesWithAB do
    /* line is guaranteed to ONLY start with a or b */
```

So, to be clear: if you use tried and tested code/patterns, it is bad style. That, and mutating the list in-memory the way you appear to via clear_lines() loses you thread safety and any hopes of parallelism that you could have had.

Comment: As a note, the python syntax for this would be a generator expression: ``(line for line in lines if line.startswith("a") or line.startswith("b"))``.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the (unnecessary) imperative implementation of `clear_lines` is really a bad idea. In Python you would probably use generators to avoid loading the complete file in memory.

Comment: What happens when the input file is larger than available memory?

Comment: @Blrfl: well, if the term generator is consistent between c#/f#/python, then what @tokland and @Lattyware translates into c#/f# yield and/or yield! statements. It's a bit more obvious in my f# example because Seq.filter can only be applied to collections of IEnumerable<T> but both code examples will work if `lines` is a generated collection.

Comment: @mcwise: When you start looking at all of the other available functions that operate this way it starts getting really sexy and incredibly expressive because they can all be chained and composed together. Look at `skip`, `take`, `reduce` (`aggregate` in .NET), `map` (`select` in .NET), and there's more but that's a really solid start.

Answer (score 14):

I recently had to implement a firmware programmer using the [Motorola S-record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_%28file_format%29) format, very similar to what you describe.  Since we had some time pressure, my first draft ignored redundancies and made simplifications based on the subset I actually needed to use in my application.  It passed my tests easily, but failed hard as soon as someone else tried it.  There was no clue what the problem was.  It got all the way through but failed at the end.

So I had no choice but to implement all the redundant checks, in order to narrow down where the issue was.  After that, it took me around two seconds to find the issue.

It took me maybe two hours extra to do it the right way, but wasted a day of other people's time as well in troubleshooting.  It's very rare that a few processor cycles are worth a day of wasted troubleshooting.

That being said, where reading files are concerned, it's often beneficial to design your software to work with reading it and processing it one line at a time, rather than reading the entire file into memory and processing it in memory.  That way it will still work on very large files.

Comment: "It's very rare that a few processor cycles are worth a day of wasted troubleshooting." Thanks for the answer, you have a good point.

Answer (score 5):

You can raise an exception in `else` case. This way it's not redundant. Exceptions aren things that aren't supposed to happen but are checked anyway.

```
clear_lines() # removes every other line than those starting with "a" or "b"
for line in lines:
    if (line.startsWith("a)):
        # do stuff
    if (line.startsWith("b")):
        # magic
    else:
        throw BadLineException
# ...
```

Comment: I would argue the latter is a bad idea, as it's less explicit - if you later decide to add a ``"c"``, it could be less clear.

Comment: First suggestion has merit... the second (assume "b") is a bad idea

Comment: @Lattyware I improved the answer. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Andrew I improved the answer. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

In [design by contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract), one guesses each function must do its job as described in its documentation. So, each function has a list of pre-conditions, that is, conditions on the function's inputs as well as post-conditions, that is, conditions of the function's output.

The function must guarantee to its clients that, if the inputs respect the pre-conditions, then the output will be as described by the post-conditions. If at least one of the pre-conditions is not respected, the function can do what it wants (crash, return any result, ...). Therefore pre and post-conditions are a semantic description of the function.

Thanks to contract, a function is sure its clients use it correctly and a client is sure the function does its job correctly.

Some languages handle contracts natively or through a dedicated framework. For the others, the best is to check the pre and post-conditions thanks to asserts, as @Lattyware said. But I would not call that defensive programming, since in my mind this concept is more focused on the protection against the (human) user's inputs.

If you exploit contracts, you can avoid the redundantly checked condition since either the called function perfectly works and you don't need the double check, or the called function is dysfunctional and the calling function can behave as it wants.

The harder part is then to define which function is responsible of what, and to strictly document these roles.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need the clear_lines() at the start. If the line is neither "a" or "b", the conditionals simply won't trigger. If you want to get rid of those lines then make the else into a clear_line(). As it stands you are doing two passes through your document. If you skip the clear_lines() at the beginning and do it as part of the foreach loop then you cut your processing time in half.

It's not only bad style, it's bad computationally.

Comment: It could be that those lines are being used for something else, and they need to be dealt with before dealing with the ``"a"``/``"b"`` lines. Not saying it's likely (the *clear* name implies they are being discarded), just that there is a possibility it's needed. If that set of lines is repeatedly iterated over in the future, it could also be worthwhile to remove them beforehand to avoid a lot of pointless iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to do anything if you find an invalid string (output debug text for example) then I'd say that's absolutely fine.  A couple of extra lines and a few months down the line when it stops working for some unknown reason you can look at the output to find out why.

If, however, it's safe to just ignore it, or you know for certain you will never get an invalid string then there's no need for the extra branch.

Personally I'm always for putting in at least a trace output for any unexpected condition - it  makes life much easier when you have a bug with output attached telling you exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> ... suppose there is a text file which contains lines starting with "a", lines starting with "b" and other lines and I actually only want to work with the first two sort of lines. My code would look something like this (using python, but read it as pseudocode):

```
# ...
clear_lines() # removes every other line than those starting with "a" or "b"
for line in lines:
    if ...
```

I hate `if...then...else` constructions.  I would avoid the whole issue:

```
process_lines_by_first_character (lines,  
                                  'a' => { |line| ... a code ... },
                                  'b' => { |line| ... b code ... } )
```